# Having problems with npm installing yo

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 873 packages, and audited 874 packages in 21s

58 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

15 vulnerabilities (13 moderate, 2 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: And... did you run `npm audit` or `npm audit fix`? Most of these warnings are things that the owners of those packages need to resolve, not you. I expect `yo` did install.

Comment: Yes, literally five minutes ago. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.